# Prolog sum distance between list of nodes ids

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

```
node(1,22,44).
node(2,43,53).
node(3,23,12).

distance(Id1,Id2,D) :-
    node(Id1,X1,Y1),
    node(Id2,X2,Y2),
    D is sqrt((X2-X1)^2 + (Y2-Y1)^2).

distancePath([X,Y],D) :-
    distance(X,Y,D).
distancePath([H,X|T],Distance) :-
    distancePath([X|T],Rest),
    distance(H,X,D),
    Aux is Rest + D,
    Distance is Distance + Aux.
```

I have some kind of problem on the distancePath because when i run `distancePath([1,2,3],Distance).` it give me "Instantiation error in argument 2 of (is)/2" can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Distance is Distance + Aux.` does not make much sense. Variables are immutable, this means once set the variable will keep the same value in that branch of the Prolog evaluation. Furthermore `Distance` is unbounded, hence the error.

You actually already have the value for `Distance`: it is `Aux` since it is the distance for the `Rest` of the list, plus the distance `D`:

```
distancePath([X,Y], D) :-
    distance(X,Y,D).

distancePath([H,X|T], Aug) :-
    distancePath([X|T],Rest),
    distance(H,X,D),
    Aux is Rest + D.
```

This then gives us:

```
?- distancePath([1,2,3], D).
D = 68.4652982294199 ;
false.
```

The above is however not very efficient: it does not make use of tail recursion, and furthermore you perform unpacking of the cons constructor multiple times. You can make use of a helper predicate to boost efficiency:

```
distancePath([X|T], Result) :-
    distancePath(T, X, 0, Result).

distancePath([], _, D, D).
distancePath([J|T], I, Di, Do) :-
    distance(I, J, Dd),
    D2 is Di + Dd,
    distancePath(T, J, D2, Do).
```